# Unchecked array cast in generic method

Tags: java, arrays, list, generics

Consider the following simple code that converts a typed List to a typed array:

```
public static <T> T[] toArray(List<T> list) {
    T[] array = (T[]) new Object[list.size()];
    int index = 0;
    for(T t: list) {
        array[index++] = t;
    }

    return array;
}
```

Since it's not possible to instantiate a generic type primitive array as such:

```
T[] array = new T[list.size()];
```

it's necessary to cast the generic type array T[] to an object array Object[]. However, this produces an "unchecked cast" warning in an IDE. What is the optimal solution to this?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java

Comment: You need to pass some token in to the method like a `Class<T>`, `IntFunction<T>` or `T[]`. There's no other way.